# New full-screen share UI - move app to top

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, share-menu

In Android 5's new share UI - full-screen, with "prioritized" apps - how do I move arbitrary app into the top, priority section? Not my app, just one that I use often.

Say I want to move "Drive" to the top section.
Is there a way to remove G+ from the top section?

[image: IMG:]

Comment: argh .. I realized it's a YouTube's own chooser thingie.

Answer (score 0):

It is prioritized according to frequency of use. Whichever apps house most for sharing will eventually go to the top of the list, and they will be sorted in alphabetical order.

Comment: hmm .. I use one of the apps several times daily, likely > 200 times since the UI change and it still lonely sits at the bottom ...

Comment: I did say they are alphabetically sorted.

Comment: The app I want to use happens to be at the bottom of the *second* section. Additionally, I haven't used *any* other apps that offer share intent.

Comment: Well,that's how it was supposed to work anyway.